# sonarqube MSBuild.Runner v0.9 searches CodeAnalysisLog.xml in wrong directory

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube

I've been trying to get the MsBuild integration between TFS2013.4 and sonarqube working as it would make my build a lot more efficient. [I do this following the procedure that has been announced here](http://www.sonarqube.org/announcing-sonarqube-integration-with-msbuild-and-team-build/).

This has been working nicely up until the point where the FxCop analysis starts. For some reason, sonarqube searches the CodeAnalysisLog.xml file in a directory `<TfsBuildBaseDir>\BuildName\Sources\Solution\Project\bin\release\` instead of the directory `<TfsBuildBaseDir>\BuildName\Binaries\`. (image added below) To me this behavior is strange as it seems to me that the process tries to locate the CodeAnalysisLog.xml on a location that is normally used on a local computer instead of a buildserver. This means that the build fails on the point where the postbuild actions are being executed, which renders the complete analysis operation useless. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: We're about to release the MSBuild Runner 1.0 - it would be great if you could try again in a bit with the new version

Comment: @Dinesh-SonarSourceTeam cool! where can I find it?  Or is the code on github stable?

Comment: it will be available by the end of the day - it's not released yet

Comment: version 1.0 is now out - can you give it a new try with C# 4.1 as well? http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin & http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+MSBuild+SonarQube+Runner ?

Comment: bad news... I have installed both components, but I still get errors. The difference is now that the codeanalysislog.xml file is not referenced anymore in the generated sonar-project.properties xml file. Am I missing something?

Comment: The SonarQube integration targets do override some of the FxCop-related MSBuild properties (e.g. to control the set of rules that are run). However, they don't change the name or location of the XXX.CodeAnalysisLog.xml file.
I've just compared builds using TFS2013 with and without the MSBuild.Runner and in both cases the log file is generated under the bin directory.
Where is the log file generated to in your builds if you don't run the MSBuild Runner?
FYI the generated properties file won't include a reference to the FxCop log file if the log file couldn't be located.